# Read Particular XML Node (values, not just InnerText) AND put the values in TextBox

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

I have been struggling for a week now and because I can not resolve this issue on my own I ask for your assistance.

I am making a C# WinForm project and am to the point where I have to read a specific part of an xml node ( mostly with 2 properties ) and have to put the 2 properties into 2 different textboxes. I have tried with the standard XML commands and the LINQ to XML commands both don't work. I will paste the part of the xml with the part of my code. Thank you all for the assistance and guidance.

XML:

```
<xsd xmlns="https://www.imsglobal.org/sites/default/files/xsd/ims_qtiasiv1p2p1.xsd">
    <title title="SMALL TEST 1" ident="0">
    <intro> SOME INTRO TEXT </intro>
    <item title="Single_choice 1" ident="1">
```

C# code:

```
FileStream READER = 
        new FileStream(ShowPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

XmlDocument Test = new XmlDocument();
Test.Load(READER);
Test.Load(ShowPath);
XmlNodeList NodeList = Test.GetElementsByTagName("xsd");
XmlNode Title = Test.SelectSingleNode("//title[@title='SMALL TEST 1']");
```

And also I have not managed to find how to navigate to a specific node in the xml. The XElement just returns some errors. Thank you all again for the help!

Comment: My first thought: Is your XML node `<title ...>` correct? It does not seem to be terminated. Perhaps it should be either `<title ... />` or `<title ...></title>`? The same may also go for `<item>`. It might be better if you posted a more complete example of the XML.

Comment: Thank you for that Kjartan :) but I ensure you the xml is properly done it is a long one so I just posted the particular part that can help me start off I will do the rest myself after I learn how. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

> *"..And also I have not managed to find how to navigate to a specific node in the xml"*

The core problem here is, that your XML has *default namespace* :

```
xmlns="https://www.imsglobal.org/sites/default/files/xsd/ims_qtiasiv1p2p1.xsd"
```

That means *all* XML elements shown in the question are considered in this namespace (because descendant elements without prefix inherit ancestor's default namespace implicitly). This concept applies whether you're using `XmlDocument` or the more favorable LINQ-to-XML.

Now, to access elements in namespace with XPath, you need to use `XmlNamespaceManager`, register a prefix to reference your XML default namespace, and then use the registered prefix properly in your XPath, something like this :

```
var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsMgr.AddNamespace("d", "https://www.imsglobal.org/sites/default/files/xsd/ims_qtiasiv1p2p1.xsd");

XmlNode Title = Test.SelectSingleNode("//d:title[@title='SMALL TEST 1']");
```

Comment: har07 thank you very much for the answer i will have to read it a couple more time ( some of the terminology is unknown to me ) do you have more suggestions for me? Thank you very much again for your time and attention !

Comment: I have removed the namespace.

Then I try:
' public string ShowPath { get; set; } ( that pases the file location after an OpenFileDialog )
FileStream READER = new FileStream(ShowPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            XDocument Test = XDocument.Load(ShowPath);

            Console.WriteLine(Test);

            XElement Title = Test.Element("title");

            Console.WriteLine(Title); '

But the second Console.WL returns nothing why?

Comment: Try with `XElement Title = Test.Root.Element("title");` instead

Comment: thank you for the last suggestion I have tried it but that still does not return anything

Comment: @chering Not sure. Worked fine for me, see the demo here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/vLkEVb

Comment: i have looked into the demo and it works there. I must have some other issues along the way maybe. Thank you very much for the time and effort that you have put into my issue. I will try to resolve this. Thank you very much again ! :)

Comment: @chering No problem at all. Don't hesitate to post another question if you get stuck with the other issue. Some suggestions though for your future questions, 1. keep your sample XML valid so that people can test and be sure that what they suggest works, 2. create a demo in dotnetfiddle, if possible, surely make it easier for us to diagnose & spot your problem.

Comment: Dear Hanif thank you again. I have followed your guide and to this point the code work. I have one final ( for now :D ) questio, As showed dotnetfiddle.net/7RHnP1 here how to make it read the second item ? In my xml I have multiple items like that. Thank you allot once again ! :)

Comment: These lengthy comments is hardly useful for future visitors. Better post a new question for a problem that isn't in the original question. Brief clue: `Element()` only accepts element name as parameter, it can't handle XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer your second question, that is on a comment, I would say, that on the code you post ( please, next time use coding frame for that ), inside the Test element, there is, I assume, an namespace

```
https://www.imsglobal.org/sites/default/files/xsd/ims_qtiasiv1p2p1.xsd
```

So, if you ask for the "title" element of test, you would not obtain what you expect, unless you set first the namespace by using XmlNamespaceManager, and then

```
 //NameSpaceAssociatedString:title
```

with SelectSingleNode

That is because, xml methods needs some way of finding identical tags between different namespaces.

For example

```
<xsd xmlns="namespace1">
    <title title="SMALL TEST 1" ident="0">
</xsd>

<xsd xmlns="namespace2">
    <title title="SMALL TEST 1" ident="0">
</xsd>
```

PD:
The code you put on comments, it works for me under .net 4.5 c# console app. No idea why it would not work for you.

Hope it helps,
Jose
[Moralzarzal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moralzarzal) - Madrid
Spain